# How to assign a formatted date to a bash script variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to automate a script and I need to capture the abbreviated name of the previous month in a variable (e.g. in June, I need the variable to return May). I have the following script, but I'm having trouble assigning it to a variable:

`date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-1)-1 month" +%b`

Running the above returns 'May'

But `mo=date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-1)-1 month" +%b`
throws this error: -ksh: -ksh: not found [No such file or directory]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you tagging this _bash_, when you in fact run _ksh_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need command substitution to capture the output of a command:

```
mo=$(date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-1)-1 month" +%b)
   ~~                                          ~
```